# OSGi Remote DS product configuration works only inside Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, export, osgi, apache-zookeeper

I'm working on Eclipse STS 2.7.2 with Java JDK 1.6, Windows XP SP3. I work behind a proxy which requires authentication.

I wrote two simple client and server plugins which work using DS and Zookeeper discovery. They refer to an IHello interface bundled in a third plugin.

The server publishes a simple Hello service which returns a string "hello" when invoked on 192.16.23.28:6666/hello and starts Zookeper with VM arguments

```
-Dzoodiscovery.dataDir=bla
-Dzoodiscovery.flavor=zoodiscovery.flavor.standalone=192.168.23.28:3030;clientPort=3031
```

xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<scr:component xmlns:scr="NOLINKALLOWED" name="it.eng.test.remote.ds.helloservice">
<implementation class="it.eng.test.remote.ds.helloservice.HelloService"/>
<property name="service.exported.interfaces" type="String" value="*"/>
<property name="service.exported.configs" type="String" value="ecf.generic.server"/>
<property name="ecf.exported.containerfactoryargs" type="String" value="ecftcp://192.168.23.28:6666/hello"/>
<service>
<provide interface="it.eng.test.remote.ds.hello.IHello"/>
</service>
</scr:component>
```

the client starts Zookeeper with VM arguments

```
-Dzoodiscovery.autoStart=true
-Dzoodiscovery.flavor=zoodiscovery.flavor.standalone=192.168.23.28:3031;clientPort=3030
```

In both cases the OSGi framework is started with the `-console -consoleLog -clean` arguments.

I then created two separated run configuration for both server and client (Run as->run configurations..) adding all required bundles (most important ones: `org.eclipse.ecf.provider.remoteservice` and `org.eclipse.ecf.provider.zookeeper`) and their dependencies.

Based on that configuration I defined two separated product configurations (new->product definition->select run configuration) for both client and server.

Now, if I run them by clicking on the link "Launch an Eclipse application" inside the respective product configuration, everything works. The server publishes the service, the client gets it and shows "Hello" on output. `netstat -a | grep 6666` shows that someone is listening on that port and `netstat -a | grep 30` shows that port 3030 and 3031 are being used.

Eclipse is configured to use my proxy correctly.

If I export them as an Eclipse product based on the aforementioned configurations (export->eclipse product->select product configuration), I get two folders: client and server.

Inside them there's everything needed to run the applications inside an external OSGi framework, including configuration files for both the framework (`config.ini`) and the VM (`eclipse.ini`).

The applications are started with `STS.exe -console` which opens an OSGi console with all the required bundles installed and started.

Starting the server works, I see someone listening on 6666 and zookeeper reports that the service has been published.

If I start the client, nothing happens. No output, no connections on 3030 and 3031, no errors. It simply does nothing, zookeeper however says it has started discovery.

Using localhost instead of my IP changes nothing, it still works inside Eclipse but not outside.

Comment: Please turn your answer into a real answer below. You can mark it as accepted after two days. That will make the question go away from the Unanswered Questions tab.

Comment: Great! I've removed the answer from your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exported application had its configuration stored in: ./eclipse.ini and the OSGi framework configuration was in ./configuration/config.ini

eclipse.ini contained the parameters needed by the Java VM for zookepeer to work:

```
-consoleLog
-console
-clean
-vmargs
-Declipse.ignoreApp=true
-Dosgi.noShutdown=true
-Dzoodiscovery.autoStart=true;
-Dzoodiscovery.flavor=zoodiscovery.flavor.standalone=localhost:3031;clientPort=3030
```

Launching the application was ok but that file wasn't read.

manually launching the application as:

```
java -Dzoodiscovery.autoStart=true; -Dzoodiscovery.flavor=zoodiscovery.flavor.standalone=192.168.23.28:3031;clientPort=3030 -jar org.eclipse.osgi_3.7.0.v20110613.jar -console -configuration c:\temp\zooc\configuration\
```

from within ./plugins where all the jars were worked.

Guess the .exe made automatically by Eclipse wasn't well configured to read its config file.